# High Intensity problem in medical imaging: image processing or machine learning solution

Tags: python, image-processing

During image clicking, some of the medical images contains very **high intensity**, which is **adding noise** to the image, due to which information in the image is lost somewhere. Is there any **standardised process** to remove the high intensity for varied set of images or any **machine learning techniques** to be applied. I suppose the problem statement could be very common. 
Please guide me to the appropriate resource.
[image: High Intensity Image sample]

Comment: I came across N4ITK resource for bias field correction in the case of MRI imaging, Will this technique work as well. Has anyone tried applying N4ITK/N3 on non . MRI images

Comment: Could you please clarify your question further? What is "image clicking"? What type of images are we talking about? What is adding noise to the image, and why? The image you posted shows an overexposed image, where pixel values are clipped (or saturated). Is this what you refer to as noise?

Comment: Cris, you are right. The overexposure i.e high intensity is itself is a noise while taking images with specific camera. If the camera is at far distant, intensity problem fades away but information also lost when we take images from far distance.I want to reduce intensity from these images

Comment: What type of camera is this? In any case, the image is overexposed, information is lost, you cannot recover that. You will have to fix the problem at the source: fix the illumination, and/or the exposure settings in the camera.

Comment: What Cris said. Other possibilities may be to add a neutral density filter over lens, reduce ISO/sensitivity of camera sensor, acquire in 10/12/14-bit raw format rather than JPEG for higher dynamic range - none of which may be possible with your setup, as I am guessing based on experience with SLR cameras.